# Cannot delete files via FTP, IIS permissions errors?

Tags: wordpress, iis, ftp

So, I am having some problems with a site that I am working on. The FTP client won't let me delete files and because of this, I can't upgrade the user's WordPress plugins. I tried CHMODding it, but to no avail and through the magic of `phpinfo();`, this is what I could gather:

```
$_SERVER["OS"] = Windows_NT
$_SERVER["USERDOMAIN"] = WORKGROUP
$_SERVER["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] = Microsoft-IIS/7.5
```

I wonder, is there any way from this end to overcome the permissions issues I am having?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have change permissions you do not have "Full Control" and therefor cannot change permissions. In fact, that'd defeat the entire purpose of restricting users to read only if they could just change their own permissions to read/write.

So the answer is no. You can't change this without having full control over the directory in the first place.